# Postgresql stored procedure on .net Core()

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to move our current SQL Server database to PostgreSQL with .net Core 2.2.

I converted all tables (constraints, index), views and stored procedures to Postgre SQL. I have keep all Dbset configuration(except for Connection string) for data models on backend.

I have a problem about running stored procedure (in Postgres) within EF Core. Stored procedure returns a view. Try to map this view to DbSet with `FromSql()` method from Ef Core. It was running with SQL Server before

The stored procedure in Postgre SQL:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getbyusername_vw_sys_menu_lang()
 RETURNS SETOF "VW_SYS_MENU_LANG"
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $$

    --return query
    SELECT M.* FROM "VW_SYS_MENU_LANG" M
    where M."USERNAME" = 'Admin' -- parameters will be added
    limit 10;

$$;
```

I got error in .net Core :

> The required column 'ID' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.

```
 var sql = "SELECT GETBYUSERNAME_VW_SYS_MENU_LANG()";
//var sql = "SELECT * FROM VW_SYS_MENU_LANG" //it works with view
 var result1 = dbSet.FromSql(sql) //error : The required column 'ID' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.
```

**MyDbcontext : DbContext**
   ....
   ....

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<VW_SYS_MENU_LANG>(e => { e.HasKey(t => new { t.ID, t.LANG }); });
```

In postgres, I can run stored procedure without any error and it return the result as expected and **ID** column does exist with capital characters. I have converted all tables and column names as **Capital** letters.

I think something should be edited on DbContext class on EF Core or Postgres stored procedure.

------------ **UPDATE**  -------------

Confused a bit , I was using Dbeaver to create and test PostgreSQL tables , functions etc.

When I run **SELECT GETBYUSERNAME_VW_SYS_MENU_LANG()** function on Dbeaver it returns table with all columns and data:

[image: Bbeaver]

When I run same function on **Pgadmin** , result is :

[image]

Comment: PostgreSQL is case sensitive. if you create a table with a column named Id via a sql script, it will be stored as "Id" so if you refer to it as id or ID, it might not find it. On the other hand SQL Server is case insensitive, you won't have this problem.

Comment: Yes , i have noticed postgre is case sensitive. So i have created all table and column names with capital letters. I have double checked and it seems all of them are capital

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be

```
SELECT * from GETBYUSERNAME_VW_SYS_MENU_LANG()
```

instead of

```
SELECT GETBYUSERNAME_VW_SYS_MENU_LANG()
```

It was hard to find the differences as a rookie PostgreSQL dev.
2nd returns one column with all data, comma separated. 1st returns all columns of table(or view)